# Add to backstack when change appears in the current fragment

Tags: android, back-stack

Sometimes I update some stuffs in the view but I don't replace the fragment. I would like that when the user click on the "back" button, he gets back the previous values.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would have to track those changes yourself and intercept the back button.  Another option would be to create a new fragment when the data changes and add the old one to the stack.

Comment: I wanna avoid to create a new instance of fragment...
How to track these changes ?

Comment: Without any source code, there is no way to say for sure how to accomplish that.  However, whenever you update your view, you would need to save the data from the old view and reload it when the user hits the back button.  Of course creating a new fragment would take care of all that for you.